# How to represent a numerical table (for example a contingency table) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, multidimensional-array, contingency

In C the easiest way would be using a bi-dimensional array. What about Haskell? A list of lists does not seem an elegant solution.
What would you suggest?

Answer (score 5):

Haskell has extensive collection of [Arrays](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays), [Vectors](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Vector_Tutorial), and other containers.

To choose between one of them, you need to know your requirements in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Multi-dimensional array literals can be described using list *syntax* but with whichever underlying data type you feel is most appropriate. E.g.

```
x :: Array U DIM3 Int
x = fromListUnboxed (Z :. (3::Int) :. (3::Int) :. (3::Int))
           [1,2,3
           ,4,5,6
           ,7,8,9

           ,10,11,12
           ,13,14,15
           ,16,17,18

           ,19,20,21
           ,22,23,24
           ,25,26,27]
```

Is a 3 dimensional array (type `DIM3 Int`). The concrete syntax can be given in list notation (either flat or nested), and the compiler will take care of the object construction.

Comment: thanks for your answer. May I ask you what `.` (or `:.`?) operator is?

Comment: @fstab Operators starting with `:` are data constructors. It's presumably what's constructing the size of the array here.

Comment: so it's like he's building a list, but what is the dot?

Comment: @fstab `:.` is an operator on its own.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz : unfortunately it's very difficult to google `:.`, so if it's not the data constructor, what is it?